# wordpress dafault image uploader is not working

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

When I am trying to uploading a image by wordpress default media uploader its showing an error. It was working fine but suddenly has stopped working. May it could happen due to any code of functions.php. I faced same problem before but after removing some code from functions.php the problem was solved. Now same issue. Is there any way to fix it any how?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and tried below line in `wp-config.php`

```
define('UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads');
```

You can try it.

Comment: There was an error at the beginning of <?php, I have fixed it.